# PHP - echo file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/server/main/' . $filename) not reachable

Tags: php

I have been trying to reach some files thru glob with the extension .vic thru php file_get_contents.
The problem I ran into is that it does not work.

My code:

```
<?php
$fileList = glob('*.vic');
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/server/main/';
foreach($fileList as $filename) {
   echo file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/server/main/' . $filename) . "\r\n";
}
```

When I run it echo's the folder I need but the file content doesn't show up.
There is a .vic file in the folder with file contents.
Did I do something wrong or is this not posible

PHP Output:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/server/main/
```

Comment: Try: `$fileList = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/server/main/*.vic');`

Comment: Yep that worked great! Thank you for helping If you post as answer I can vote up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`$fileList = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/server/main/*.vic');`